# JPA many to many cascading delete

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, toplink

I've just started with JEE6 using netbeans IDE, and now i'm learning JPA with toplink.
I'm using Netbeans IDE and mySQL.

I created 2 very simple tables, with a many to many relationship:

```
table student
int id PK
varchar name

table teacher
int id PK
varchar name

//the mapping
table studentTeacher
int studentID FK
int teacherID FK
```

The studentTeacher table maps Students id to Teachers id, with cascade on delete and update.

I've used the 'generate entities from database' netbeans feature, and it works fine:
I can add a Student object to my student table, and i can add a Teacher object to my teacher table.

The problem is, how can i create a 'studentTeacher' entity and persist it? Or it's already done by the IDE?

Here is the auto-generated Annotations from Netbeans:

```
 //Student Entity annotation generated by Netbeans 7.0.1

 @Id
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Integer id;
 @Size(max = 40)
 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;
 @JoinTable(name = "studentTeacher", joinColumns =
 {
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentID", referencedColumnName = "id")
 }, inverseJoinColumns =
 {
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacherID", referencedColumnName = "id")
 })
 @ManyToMany
 private Collection<Teacher> teacherCollection;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Properly speaking, it's already done by the JPA implementation, in your case: TopLink. You don't need a `StudentTeacher` entity as it isn't an entity by itself, it's just an auxiliary table needed by the Entity-Relational scheme in order to model your many-to-many relationship.

If your relation between `Student` and `Teacher` had additional attributes apart from the foreign keys of both entities, then you will need an additional entity but you already existent entities (`Student` and `Teacher`) will no longer have a many-to-many relationship, but a one-to-many/many-to-one with that intermediary `StudentTeacher` entity.

My advice, if your model is as simple as in your example, leave as it is.

Comment: Great, but how can i populate the studentTeacher table? What really matters in this case is the mapping provided by this table. I'm confused, buying a book now.

Comment: You need to handle the lists that map the many-to-many relationship carefully, so, if you add a `Teacher` to your `Student` entity, then be sure that you also add that `Student` instance to the previous mentioned `Teacher`. Doing so JPA will perform the "population" of your intermediary table when you invoke `EntityManager.persist(student)` or `EntityManager.persist(teacher)` (and the same with any other method)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that and start JPA from the beginning.

Comment: I created a Student and an ArrayList of Teachers for this student, and   persist the student. The intermediate table became filled automatically, no need to add the student to each teacher (i'm not sure if i understood your comment).

Comment: If you do that in a single operation that's fine, but If your relationship is bidirectional and you are working with the entities independently, you may need to refresh the `Teacher` side of it or perform a new query. What I mean is JPA will populate the intermediary table, but will not fill the list in the other side of the relationship unless you ask for that by means of a refresh or a new query.